# Determine IP address/es of Azure Container Instances

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

Is there way to determine outbound IPs specific to Azure Container Instances?

Background:
I would like to allow my container instance to send network messages to service behind firewall. To configure this firewall I need to know outbound IP address or range of IPs.

I found list of IPs for my region here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519 but it's for all services (for my region it's more than 180 entries) not only container instances.

Comment: In Azure, all the public IP is random assign. So you cannot know it before you create it. I think you can create a static public IP for your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use Private IP, VNet deployment feature (in preview currently) of ACI to support this. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet

You can use the CIDR range of the subnet to configure your firewall.

HTH

Comment: Please observe that ACI in VNets are not supported in all Azure Regions. See this overview table for availability: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-region-availability

Answer (score 0):

You can have container infos by executing this "Azure CLI" command

```
az container show --resource-group "RgName" --name "containerName" --output table
```